# Reversing a String in C from scratch

Tags: c, reverse, c-strings, strlen, function-definition

I am trying to reverse an array of strings in C for a school project. Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char * str) {
  char * p1 = str;
  int len = strlen(str) - 1;
  char temp;
  int m;

  for (m=0; m<(len/2); m++){
      temp = str[len];
      str[len]= str[m];
      str[m]=temp;
      len=len-1;
  }
  return;
}                                                                                                          

int main(void) {
  char str0[] = "";
  char str1[] = "123";
  char str2[] = "abcd";
  char str3[] = "Captain's log, Stardate 42523.7";
  char str4[] = "Hello, my name is Inigo Montoya.";
  char str5[] = "You can be my wingman anyday!";
  char str6[] = "Executor Selendis! Unleash the full power of your forces! There may be no tomorrow!";
  char * array[] = {str0, str1, str2, str3, str4, str5, str6};
  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    reverse(array[i]);
    printf("%s\n", array[i]);
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I wrote the reverse function. The problem is when I compile and run the code, it gives the expected result for all the strings up to str3[]. But after that, it messes up the order. Here is the output

```
321
dbca
7.32524 etlog, Starda s'niatpaC
.ayotnoM oname is Inig ym ,olleH
!yadyna ne my wingmab nac uoY
!worromot on eb yam erehT !the full power of your forces hsaelnU !sidneleS rotucexE
```

I dont't know why it works for some strings but fails at the others. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to use an `end` variable that you move around and leave len alone. I think but have not verified that the problem is (len/2) while you keep shortening len.

Comment: I would advice that len should only ever change if whatever it is the measure of, also changes.  Start using variable names like `idx` or something with that pre/post-fix for indexing variables.  It's easier to keep them sorted from variables used for magnitude or counting (len is a magnitude, count or counter for counting, etc.).   Counts and other magnitudes are often used for limits and should generally have stable values until they are not used or reset. Indexing variables may seem like a counter, but that's not their primary role in your code, they are used as offsets into your arrays.

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to have two variables (e.g.) `left` and `right`.

`left` is incremented and `right` is decremented as long as: `left < right`

Here's two ways. One uses index variables. The other uses pointer variables:

```
#include <string.h>

void
reverse_byidx(char *str)
{
    int left = 0;
    int right = strlen(str) - 1;
    char temp;

    for (;  left < right;  ++left, --right) {
        temp = str[left];
        str[left] = str[right];
        str[right] = temp;
    }
}

void
reverse_byptr(char *str)
{
    char *left = str;
    char *right = &str[strlen(str) - 1];
    char temp;

    for (;  left < right;  ++left, --right) {
        temp = *left;
        *left = *right;
        *right = temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In yout `for` loop, you use `len/2` as the boundary condition, but you ALSO modify `len` in the loop, which means you end up stopping the loop before you should.

Its actually quite simple to fix -- change the loop condition to:

```
for (m=0; m<len; m++){
```

alternately, make a copy of `len` and decrement that:

```
for (m=0, e=len; m<(len/2); m++, e--){
  temp = str[e];
  str[e]= str[m];
  str[m]=temp;
```

}

Comment: `m<(len/2)` as the loop condition doesn't work because in the OP's code `len` is equal to `strlen(str) - 1`... You could use `m<e`as the condition instead.

Comment: @isrnick: `m < (len/2)` works fine -- there's no need to swap the middle character with itself in an odd length string (which is all that would happen if the -1 wasn't there.)  `m < e` works equally well (and avoids needing the /2)

Comment: `m<(len/2)` would fail on even-lengthed strings.  Say you had a string of length 4, then `len` would be 3.  3/2 = 1.  The loop would end after one iteration as `m<(len/2)`-> `1<1` evaluates to false.

Comment: In this case `m < (len/2)` fails for even length strings (not odd), the middle characters are not swapped.

Answer (score 1):

You modify `len` variable in a loop, so it doesn't keep string length anymore. Instead you can use following code:

```
 for (m = 0; m < (len + 1) / 2; m++) {
     temp = str[len - m]; // m symbol from end
     str[len - m] = str[m];
     str[m] = temp;
 }
```

Comment: Yeah, `len/2` doesn't work as the condition since `len` is actually `strlen() - 1`

Comment: You could use `m < len - m` as the for loop's condition.

Answer (score 1):

For starters the value of the variable `len` is being changed in the loop

```
for (m=0; m<(len/2); m++){
    //...
    len=len-1;
}
```

As a result the condition `m<(len/2` in the loop is also being changed.

But if you will introduce an intermediate variable for the index for right side hand elements of the loop instead of using the  variable `len` as it is suggested here in other answers in any case the loop will be invalid.

The problem of your function `reverse` in this case is that you decremented the variable `len`

```
int len = strlen(str) - 1;
```

before the loop

```
for (m=0; m<(len/2); m++){
```

Thus for example if the length of the passed string is equal to `4` then the loop should look like

```
for (m=0; m < 2; m++){
```

that is the elements of the string with indices `0` and `1` will be swapped with the elements of the string with indices `3` and `2` correspondingly.

However after the decrementing the variable `len` the loop now will look like

```
for (m=0; m < 1; m++){
```

because `3 / 2` yields `1`.

For example if you will try to reverse the string `"ab"` the output will be the same

```
ab
```

because the length of the string is equal to `2` and the length minus 1 will be equal to 1. So the condition `m<(len/2)` will be equivalent to `m < 0` and the loop will not be executed.

So for strings with an even length you will get  incorrect results.

Pay attention to that instead of the type `int` used for objects that store length of strings you should use the type `size_t`. It is the type that the function `strlen` has. And moreover in general an object of the type `int` is unable to hold a value of the type `size_t` for big strings. So your function has a drawback that it will be unable to process correctly very big strings.

Also do not use magic numbers as for example `7`. Instead try to use named constants.

So the function reverse can look the following way

```
char * reverse( char *s )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0, n = strlen( s ); i < n / 2; i++ )
    {
        char c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[n-i-1];
        s[n-i-1] = c;
    }

    return s;
}
```

To output a reversed string you can just write for example in main

```
puts( reverse( array[i] ) );
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * reverse( char *s )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0, n = strlen( s ); i < n / 2; i++ )
    {
        char c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[n-i-1];
        s[n-i-1] = c;
    }

    return s;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char str0[] = "";
    char str1[] = "123";
    char str2[] = "abcd";
    char str3[] = "Captain's log, Stardate 42523.7";
    char str4[] = "Hello, my name is Inigo Montoya.";
    char str5[] = "You can be my wingman anyday!";
    char str6[] = "Executor Selendis! Unleash the full power of your forces! There may be no tomorrow!";
    char * array[] = { str0, str1, str2, str3, str4, str5, str6 };

    const size_t N = sizeof( array ) / sizeof( *array );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) 
    {
        puts( reverse( array[i] ) );
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Its output is

```
321
dcba
7.32524 etadratS ,gol s'niatpaC
.ayotnoM oginI si eman ym ,olleH
!yadyna namgniw ym eb nac uoY
!worromot on eb yam erehT !secrof ruoy fo rewop lluf eht hsaelnU !sidneleS rotucexE
```

If you want to implement the function using pointers instead of the subscript operator then the function can look like

```
char * reverse( char *s )
{
    if ( *s )    // check that the passed string is not empty
    {
        for ( char *first = s, *last = s + strlen( s ); first < --last; ++first )
        {
            char c = *first;
            *first = *last;
            *last = c;
        }
    }       

    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it like this:

```
  // here we add a back variable
  // so that we don't modify the len variable on which the for loop
  // depends, now back will be our index at the last character
  int back = len;

  for (m=0; m<(len/2); ++m){
      temp = str[back];
      str[back]= str[m];
      str[m]=temp;
      --back;
  }
```

Comment: `back -= 1` would be better form.

Comment: Even better! ;)

Comment: `m<(len/2)` as the loop condition doesn't work because in the OP's code `len` is equal to `strlen(str) - 1`... You could use `m<back` as the condition instead.

Comment: personally, I would put the `--back` in the for-loop's after-statement (or whatever it's called).  See Craig Estey's answer for how it looks (and with added bonus of a conditional that works correctly)